# Proving inequality for all real $a$ and $b$.

Tags: inequality, logarithms, real-numbers, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality

I am trying to prove the following two inequalities[image]

My first intuition was to take the natural log of both sides, then simplify them to get an obvious statement regarding a and b. But I can't reduce the natural log of the right hand-side of the inequality (because of the addition operator).

I'm feeling really stumped and dumb, so a hint would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first one:
dividing by $$e^{a+2b}\ne 0$$ and we get
$$3\le e^{2(a-b)}+\frac{2}{e^{a-b}}$$
substituting $$z=e^{a-b}$$ then we get
$$3\le z^2+\frac{2}{z}$$
can you finish?
and this is equivalent to $$0\le (z+2)(z-2)^2$$ which is true. For your send question:
we get the general case : $$\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}\geq \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^n$$

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense actually. Thanks! That was really smart

Comment: Then I would assume to take a similar approach of dividing by (a+b)^2018 for the second question

Comment: let me see, if this will work

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Does in German language sentence always start with small letter?

Comment: no it doesn't, why do you ask me?

Comment: Sonnhard, your last inequality is wrong for $n=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: the $n$ must be a natural number

Comment: $n$ can be any real number larger than $1$.  This is just the $s$-power mean.

Comment: thank you very much for your hints

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality:

By AM-GM
$$\frac{e^{3a}+2e^{3b}}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{e^{3a}\left(e^{3b}\right)^2}=e^{a+2b}$$

The second inequality it's Jensen for $f(x)=x^{2018}$:
$$\frac{a^{2018}+b^{2018}}{2}\geq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{2018}.$$

Comment: Never heard of AM-GM before but wow that's a really useful inequality to have in your back pocket

Answer (score 1):

If we divide first one with $e^{a+2b}$ we get $$3\leq (e^{a-b})^2+2e^{b-a}$$

Now let $x=e^{a-b}$ so we have to prove $$3\leq x^2+{2\over x}$$ 
which is true by inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean:

$$ x^2+{1\over x}+{1\over x} \geq 3\cdot \sqrt[3]{x^2{1\over x}{1\over x}}=3$$

Answer (score 1):

1. Use AM-GM on $e^{3a},e^{3b},e^{3b}$ so that $$\frac{e^{3a}+2e^{3b}}{3} \ge e^{a}e^{2b}$$
2. Use Jensen's inequality on $x\mapsto x^{2018}$, which is a convex function (since it has a positive second derivative except at $x=0$).
   \begin{align}
   \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{2018} &\le \frac12 a^{2018}+\frac12 b^{2018} \\
   (a+b)^{2018} &\le 2^{2017} a^{2018} + 2^{2017} b^{2018}
   \end{align}

---

Since OP starts by taking log, but none of the existing answers use log, I'll continue OP's work.

1. Take log on both sides to get

\begin{align}
e^{a+2b} &\le \frac13 e^{3a} + \frac23 e^{3b} \\
\iff a+2b &\le \log \left( \frac13 e^{3a} + \frac23 e^{3b} \right) \\
\iff \frac13 \log e^{3a} + \frac23 \log e^{3b} &\le \log \left( \frac13 e^{3a} + \frac23 e^{3b} \right) \\
\iff \frac13 f(e^{3a}) + \frac23 f(e^{3b}) &\le f \left( \frac13 e^{3a} + \frac23 e^{3b} \right),
\end{align}

which is Jensen's inequality for the concave function $f: x \mapsto \log x$.